# Understanding gamma mixture model

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, mixture-distribution

I am trying to understand the gamma mixture models, especially the significance of the 'loc' parameter in `scipy.stats`. In the code below, I generate a mixture distribution with two gamma distributions with different shape and scale parameters.

```
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#Define shape parameters
alpha1 = 2
alpha2 = 2

#Define rate parameters
beta1 = 3
beta2 = 5

#Define location parameters
loc1 = 0
loc2 = 0

#Define weights
pi_1 = 0.2

#Create gamma rvs and concatenate them to generate mixture distribution
k = st.bernoulli(pi_1).rvs(30000)
x1 = st.gamma(a = alpha1, loc = loc1, scale = 1/beta1).rvs(sum(k==1))
x2 = st.gamma(a = alpha2, loc = loc2, scale = 1/beta2).rvs(sum(k==0))
x = np.concatenate([x1,x2])

#Plot the histogram
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
sns.histplot(x=x)
plt.vlines(x1, 0, 50, color='orange', alpha=0.1)
plt.vlines(x2, 0, 50, color='green', alpha=0.1)
plt.xlabel('x')

plt.show()
```

When I have the 'loc1' and 'loc2' values as 0, I don't observe two gamma distributions visually from the histogram. The resulting histogram is visualized as a single gamma function as seen in

[image: 1]

When I change the 'loc1' = 2 and 'loc2' = 3, the resulting histogram can be seen as a mixture of two gamma distributions as in

[image: 2]

Can anyone help me to understand this difference? Is 'loc' the mean of the variables and why do two distributions with zero mean but different alpha and beta appear as a single distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the densities you're sampling from with the first set of parameter values:

[image]

The `x1` values are drawn from the green density and the `x2` from the orange density. The black density is the mixture of the two, with weights `pi_1` and `1-pi_1`, respectively. The mixture distribution doesn't have distinct peaks because the two overlap.

In your second example, you've shifted the support of both densities, i.e. instead of $(0, \infty)$, `x1` takes values in $(2, \infty)$, and `x2` takes values in $(3, \infty)$. This is the result:
[image]
Notice that the mixture density now has two distinct peaks.

Comment: Thank you very much!